# Need to print the address but getting contents

Tags: c, pointers

I keep trying different configurations of this code with "*"s, but can't get it to output the address of board. What am I missing?

We need to dynamically allocate a 2-d array for a map. I can't change the createMapBoard function line for the project, and the ** is throwing me off.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char **createMapBoard(void)
{
    int i;
    char **board;

    board = malloc(8 * sizeof(char *));
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        board[i] = malloc(8 * sizeof(char));

    strcpy(board[0],"FF      ");
    strcpy(board[1]," F      ");
    strcpy(board[2]," FF     ");
    strcpy(board[3],"  F     ");
    strcpy(board[4],"  K     ");
    strcpy(board[5],"C  B    ");
    strcpy(board[6]," CC D   ");
    strcpy(board[7],"  C  DD ");

    return board;
}

int main()
{

char *pointer = *createMapBoard();
printf("Pointer: %s\n", pointer);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you get from `createMapBoard()` is not a 2d array. One of the essential properties of an array is that values are consecutive in memory. The values pointed to by the result of `createMapBoard()` are not.

Comment: You are right, I worded that wrong. It's supposed to create a 2-d array and return the starting address.

Comment: BTW: `board[i] = malloc(8 * sizeof(char));` is wrong, `board[i] = malloc(9 * sizeof(char));` is correct, your strings need 9 bytes, 8 for the characters +1 for the NUL terminator. Read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
printf("Pointer: %s\n", pointer); // "%s" is for printing string
                  ^
```

to this:

```
printf("Pointer: %p\n", (void *)pointer); // "%p" is for printing pointer addresses
                                          // Note: cast to (void *) is optional for use with 
                                          // character types (but idiomatic),  and necessary 
                                          // for other types when using "%p" format specifier.
                  ^
```

There is a *[cheat sheet here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)* for `printf` format specifiers, including one for *pointer addresses*.

By the way, this particular format specifier is also useful for printing the address of other variable types when using it in conjunction with the `&` (*address of*) operator:

```
int int_var;

printf("This is the address of int_var: %p\n", (void *)&int_var);//note, (void *) cast is 
                                                                 //necessary here as its applied 
                                                                 //to non-character type.
```

Comment: @Osiris `char*` and `void*` have the same characteristics and so are compatible here. "A pointer to `void` shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type."  C11dr §6.2.5 28  The `void*` cast is idiomatic, though not needed.

Comment: Yes, non-character object pointers oblige the cast.  (Functions pointers are a separate concern.) Consider that on uncommon platforms, such other pointers may be of different size even.  IMO, I like to use and see the `void*` cast, yet tolerate its non-use with printing character  pointers as C allows it ( as a ... argument).

Comment: @chux Thanks, I missed that.

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems here.  First, the `%s` format specifier is used to print a string.  If you want to print the value of a pointer, use `%p` and cast the operand to `void *`:

```
printf("Pointer: %p\n", (void *)pointer);
```

Second, what you're assigning to `pointer` is actually a pointer to the first string in the board, not the whole board.  For that you want:

```
char **pointer = createMapBoard();
```

Then you can treat `pointer` as an array to iterate through the strings.